# Pre-cache a fetch with Core Data?

Tags: core-data

I've got an application using Core Data (successfully) and I have an object graph that has a few root nodes that each have a to-many to tens of thousands of children.  During my app's run, based on user input, I do the following (pseudocode):

```
Find the user selected root node,
Then fetch all its children, in ascending alphabetic order based on a property.
```

The trick here is that this data is **constant**.  My Core Data store is read-only.

Doing this fetch is very time consuming.  How can I pre-cache these results so that I completely avoid that fetch and store?  The fetched results are used to fill a UITableView.  When a user selects a cell of that tableview it drills down in to deeper data in the Core Data store - that data doesn't need to be precached..

Answer (score 1):

If you are using NSFetchedResultsController with your tableview you can set a `cacheName`. You can set a `batchSize` in NSFetchRequest to bring the results in chunks. And also make sure you set the attribute your sorting on as an index in the core data model.

Comment: I had never even heard of NSFetchedResultsController. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This code come from the [Core Data Programming](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html) guide (chapter "Core Data Performance
") and shows how to make a prefetch.

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = /* get the context */; 
NSEntityDescription *employeeEntity = [NSEntityDescription 
entityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:context]; 
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init]; 
[request setEntity:employeeEntity]; 
[request setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching: 
[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"department"]];
```

Also use a limit on what is retruned from the real fetch. That will help performance.